# Get User SID From Logon ID (Windows XP and Up)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wmi, sid

I have a Windows service that needs to access registry hives under HKEY_USERS when users log on, either locally or via Terminal Server. I'm using a WMI query on win32_logonsession to receive events when users log on, and one of the properties I get from that query is a LogonId. To figure out which registry hive I need to access, now, I need the users's SID, which is used as a registry key name beneath HKEY_USERS.

In most cases, I can get this by doing a RelatedObjectQuery like so (in C#):

```
RelatedObjectQuery relatedQuery = new RelatedObjectQuery( "associators of {Win32_LogonSession.LogonId='" + logonID + "'} WHERE AssocClass=Win32_LoggedOnUser Role=Dependent" );
```

where "logonID" is the logon session ID from the session query. Running the RelatedObjectQuery will generally give me a SID property that contains exactly what I need.

There are two issues I have with this. First and most importantly, the RelatedObjectQuery will not return any results for a domain user that logs in with cached credentials, disconnected from the domain. Second, I'm not pleased with the performance of this RelatedObjectQuery --- it can take up to several seconds to execute.

Here's a quick and dirty command line program I threw together to experiment with the queries. Rather than setting up to receive events, this just enumerates the users on the local machine:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;

namespace EnumUsersTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope( "\\\\.\\root\\cimv2" );

            string queryString = "select * from win32_logonsession";                          // for all sessions
            //string queryString = "select * from win32_logonsession where logontype = 2";     // for local interactive sessions only

            ManagementObjectSearcher sessionQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher( scope, new SelectQuery( queryString ) );
            ManagementObjectCollection logonSessions = sessionQuery.Get();
            foreach ( ManagementObject logonSession in logonSessions )
            {
                string logonID = logonSession["LogonId"].ToString();
                Console.WriteLine( "=== {0}, type {1} ===", logonID, logonSession["LogonType"].ToString() );
                RelatedObjectQuery relatedQuery = new RelatedObjectQuery( "associators of {Win32_LogonSession.LogonId='" + logonID + "'} WHERE AssocClass=Win32_LoggedOnUser Role=Dependent" );
                ManagementObjectSearcher userQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher( scope, relatedQuery );
                ManagementObjectCollection users = userQuery.Get();
                foreach ( ManagementObject user in users )
                {
                    PrintProperties( user.Properties );
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine( "\nDone! Press a key to exit..." );
            Console.ReadKey( true );
        }


        private static void PrintProperty( PropertyData pd )
        {
            string value = "null";
            string valueType = "n/a";
            if ( pd.Value != null )
            {
                value = pd.Value.ToString();
                valueType = pd.Value.GetType().ToString();
            }

            Console.WriteLine( "  \"{0}\" = ({1}) \"{2}\"", pd.Name, valueType, value );
        }


        private static void PrintProperties( PropertyDataCollection properties )
        {
            foreach ( PropertyData pd in properties )
            {
                PrintProperty( pd );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So... is there way to quickly and reliably obtain the user SID given the information I retrieve from WMI, or should I be looking at using something like SENS instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a username to a SID string in C#/.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040623/convert-a-username-to-a-sid-string-in-c-net)

Answer (score 3):

I asked [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365367/how-to-access-hkcu-registry-of-currently-logged-on-users-from-a-service) a while back and got this answer: [how to get a SID from a windows username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040623/convert-a-username-to-a-sid-string-in-c-net).

I was planning on using SystemEvents to detect when a user logs on to windows, then looping through the logged on users list at that point to detect all the logged on users. ([Here's my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077958/how-to-determine-the-current-windows-user-from-a-windows-service), about all this including references for detecting logons and current users.)

If you decide on an approach please post an update - I'd be interested to hear what you find works well.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion \ProfileList

Comment: That'll only work where a local profile exists for the user. Consider server in domain: may have many users authenticate, but only a few admins will have profiles.

Answer (score 1):

Another working answer (code in VB.Net)

```
Public Function GetSIDfromAccName(ByVal strAccName As String) As String
        Debug.WriteLine("***WMI-GetSIDfromAccName***")
        Dim strSID As String = ""
        Try
            Dim wmiClass As System.Management.SelectQuery = New System.Management.SelectQuery(("Select * from Win32_UserAccount where Name='" _
              + (strAccName + "'")))
            Dim wmiSearcher As System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher = New System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiClass)
            For Each val As System.Management.ManagementBaseObject In wmiSearcher.Get
                strSID = val("SID").ToString
            Next
        Catch e As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString)
        End Try
        Return strSID
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Powershell is easier.

```
Function GetSIDfromAcctName()
{
$myacct = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -filter "Name = '$env:USERNAME " 
write-host Name: $myacct.name
Write-Host SID : $myacct.sid
}
```

Comment: I don't think writing a Windows service in Powershell is an option, at present. I'll certainly keep this in mind if I ever have this need in a scripting situation, though.