# How do I get a local NT Service SID using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-7

I found this snippet on SO:

[Get User SID From Logon ID (Windows XP and Up)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727393/get-user-sid-from-logon-id-windows-xp-and-up)

```
Function GetSIDfromAcctName()
{
$myacct = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -filter "Name = '$env:USERNAME " 
write-host Name: $myacct.name
Write-Host SID : $myacct.sid
}
```

But it doesn't show everything.

For example, I just want the sid of "nt service\dhcp."  How can I get that?  When I run my powershell manually with

Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccont

I get all the users, but there's only three "regular" users.  None of the "special" nt service users.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the name of the account under which a service is started you can use :

```
gwmi Win32_service -Filter "name='dhcp'" | % {return $_.startname}
```

The result is `"NT Authority\LocalService"` which is a well known SID as discribed in [SID Values For Default Windows NT Installations](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/163846/en), you'll find more SIDs in [Well-known security identifiers in Windows operating systems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330/en).

---

Edited :
As you can see in the following screen shot, yes the dhcp client is running in a session started as `"NT Authority\LocalService"`

[image]

Comment: you're telling me that dhcp is really localservice?

Comment: Yes dhcp is running under localservice session.

Answer (score 4):

To get the built-in accounts you need another WMI class: `Win32_Account`.

```
gwmi -class win32_account -Filter 'name="LOCAL SERVICE"'
```