# How to identify which user is currently using the VM

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

How to identify which user is currently using the VM. That is the VM might have common login like administrator, test1 etc., but I want know which user/machine has launched the VM using mstsc from their machine and using it.

I want to fetch these information using C# or powershell code.

All the machines and VM's are in same domain.

All your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: with 1294 reputation, you should know by now that you need to demonstrate a minimal understanding of the question you are asking. What code have you tried yet? Have you attempted to google: C#.NET tell who is on VM

Comment: Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727393/get-user-sid-from-logon-id-windows-xp-and-up

Comment: @logixologist you haven't got my ques. I know to fetch the users who is in VM. But in my case, say only one user is created in my VM (administrator). So u can login as only administrator. So whatever ans u suggested will fetch administrator is in VM. But i want from which machine/user has launched the mstsc and entered the VM via common administrator login? Hope u got it

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell you could do this:

```
$sessions = gwmi -cn myvm -Query "Select * from Win32_LogonSession Where LogonType = 10"
$sessions | Foreach {gwmi -cn myvm -Query "Associators of {Win32_LogonSession.LogonID='$($_.LogonId)'} Where AssocClass=Win32_LoggedOnUser Role=Dependent"}
```

Comment: `Assoc` and `Class` where on separate lines, I don't know if that was supposed to be two words or one, please fix it if I made a mistake.

Comment: It is supposed to be one word.  Thanks for fixing the separate line issue.